# Identify whenever there is a change in table cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as follows. How to identify whenever there is a change in the value of the cell with id fpTotal and frTotal. I tried with JQuery change event but it didn't workout. Which is the suitable JS function?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" id="t01">
      <thead style="text-align:center">
         <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Rate/Unit</th>
            <th>Total No</th>
            <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <td id="fpRate" style="text-align:right">0</td>
            <td id="fpNos" style="text-align:center">0</td>
            <td>
              <div style="float:left">$</div>
              <div style="float:right" id="fpTotal">-</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th >Fractional page rate</th>
            <td id="frRate" style="text-align:right">0</td>
            <td id="frNos" style="text-align:center">0</td>
            <td>
              <div style="float:left">$</div>
              <div id="frTotal" style="float:right">-</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery change event

```
$("#fpTotal").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
});

$("#frTotal").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

Comment: How does the text change? Also, you should be using classes and not ids.

Comment: The change event only works on input type elements. What you haven't shown here is *how* the values are changing in those locations.

Comment: If you change this values from server, you must save this item value somewhere and after that you can compare this. If you try to catch Div element change it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener, something like below

```js
var fpRate = document.getElementById('fpRate');
fpRate.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',function() {
  alert(fpRate.innerHTML);
});


var fpNos = document.getElementById('fpNos');
fpNos.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',function() {
  alert(fpNos.innerHTML);
});


function changeCellData(data) {
  fpRate.innerHTML = data;
  fpNos.innerHTML = data;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" id="t01">
      <thead style="text-align:center">
         <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Rate/Unit</th>
            <th>Total No</th>
            <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <td id="fpRate" style="text-align:right">0</td>
            <td id="fpNos" style="text-align:center">0</td>
            <td>
              <div style="float:left">$</div>
              <div style="float:right" id="fpTotal">-</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th >Fractional page rate</th>
            <td id="frRate" style="text-align:right">0</td>
            <td id="frNos" style="text-align:center">0</td>
            <td>
              <div style="float:left">$</div>
              <div id="frTotal" style="float:right">-</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onClick="changeCellData('1')">Set 1</button>
```